# True or False: $\lim_{x\to 0}x/\log x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking through the exercises of An Introduction to Analysis by William R. Wade, and $4.4.0a$ is a prove or disprove question:

> $x/\log x\to 0$ as $x\to0$

According to the back of the book this is false (without explanation), but $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\log x}=\frac{0}{-\infty}=0.$$[Wolfram also agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20x/logx%20to%200). Is Wade incorrect, or is there an arguement to be made here?

Answer (score 7):

It’s false because the notation $\lim_{x\to 0}$ implies that the limit is two-sided, and the denominator is undefined to the left of $0$. The correct version is

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\ln x}=0\;.$$

(At any rate I feel quite sure that this is what the author had in mind.)

Comment: That was my original thought, too, but why can we disregard complex numbers? If we include them the statement is true.

Comment: @AlexKW It is a book on *real* analysis, is it not?

Comment: @Alex: I’ve not seen the book, but the table of contents is available at Pearson, and it indicates that the first seven chapters deal with $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, Well, yes, I agree, and I definitely see the reasoning behind it. It's just not comfortable to say $log x$ is undefined when $x$ is negative without specifying the outputs; it's like saying $\sqrt{-1}$ is undefined. It's not -- it's $i$. I suppose it's implied by the context of the book . . . But still.

Answer (score 0):

$False\:$ simply because $\:\log_e(x)\:$is not a real-value function on $\:\Re_{\:-}$